# Can we get Stack Exchange notifications when a private beta starts?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, area-51, global-inbox, private-beta

I get messages in the Stack Exchange inbox when people reply to my questions or comment on my answers, but I was surprised when I didn't get an in-site notification that one of the Area 51 sites I had committed to had entered beta.

Can we add an inbox message for when Area 51 sites enter beta if we are committed to that site?

**Update:**

When this request was originally made, notifications were much more rare.  Only answers, comments, and moderator messages would show up.

These days, we now have notifications for badges and edits with the less obtrusive grayish circle.  Since I can now get a notification for a Popular Question badge, shouldn't I also be able to get a notification of some type for a private beta starting (which is arguably much more significant)?

All other site messages use the StackExchange notification system.  It seems inconsistent to rely on email as the primary method of communication for existing members, when by default, StackExchange doesn't send emails for any other action.

Comment: You don't check email?

Comment: It still seems odd that we get notifications for comments but not for something like a beta, which is arguably more important.  Also, given the rate sites enter beta and that someone can only be committed on up to three sites at a time, it's not like there would be a flood of new messages by adding beta notifications.

Comment: That's true about non-users, and the system is probably the way it is now because it was simpler to implement.  If I had a choice though, I would much prefer a SE notification over an email, so I'll leave this as a vote for a notification.

Comment: I *never* check my email. A notification on the site would be very nice.

Comment: @Shog9 I never seem to *get* the emails, and they're not in Spam either....

Comment: Logged as sent 1 hour ago to your address on record, @Wendi. I got mine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the system certainly could add a notification, but it'd still have to send an email to anyone who wasn't already a member on another SE site. The underlying assumption is that we don't want to spam your email account about every little thing, and so you don't get emails for comments (or answers, or edits, unless you want them and don't visit the site for a while) - we assume you're checking your email even if you aren't visiting any SE sites.